# how to send byte array in json post request?

Tags: java, json, wcf

I have a  wcf service which accepts   `byte[] serialData`, now am developing a java client which needs to consume the same method.

When i sent bytearray to the service as a json post request , it is getting an exception as `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400`

Here is my code:

**wcf method:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "saveSerialNumbers", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
Dictionary<string, object> saveSerialNumbers(byte[] serialData);
```

**Java Client:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {      
                sb.append(String.valueOf(gen()));
    }
byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(sb.toString().getBytes());
String json = "{\"serialDataByte\":\""+sb.toString()+"\"}";
```

This is my postrequest method:

```
public String getResultPOST(String jsonObject,String uri,String method) throws Exception{
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri+method);
            System.out.println(url.toString());
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            OutputStreamWriter out;
            try {
                out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                  out.write(jsonObject);
                    out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            String line = "";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            in.close();
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
            //here is the exception
        }
    }
```

Here is my method call:

```
 String json = "{\"serialData\":\""+ new String(bytesEncoded)  +"\",\"guProductID\":\""+guProductID+"\",\"guStoreID\":\""+guStoreID+"\",\"securityToken\":\""+SecurityToken+"\"}";
 String serialContract  = serialClient.getResultPOST(json, "http://localhost:3361/EcoService.svc/Json/", "saveSerialNumbers");
```

Comment: why are you converting base64-string to bytes in your client? Try do not convert string to bytes and bytes to string in your client. Send bast64 string as you get it from encoder.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov You mean to send as a string?

Comment: I mean `String json = "{\"serialDataByte\":\"" + new String(bytesEncoded) + "\"}";`

Comment: In your code you are sending non-converted string, because sb buffer contains non-converted string. In my code as you have get a byte[] array of base64 encoded bytes, you compose a base64 string and include it to your json.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Still it dint work for me!

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below, there's a simple working prototype to generate json from a string instance. Use this code snippet to update your client part. And it should work.

```
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // composing string to be encoded
        sb.append("Part 1 of some text to be encoded to base64 format\n");
        sb.append("Part 2 of some text to be encoded to base64 format\n");
        sb.append("Part 3 of some text to be encoded to base64 format");


        // getting base64 encoded string bytes
        byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(sb.toString().getBytes());

        // composing json
        String json = "{\"serialDataByte\":\""+ new String(bytesEncoded) +"\"}";        

        System.out.println(json);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The code uses Java 8 SDK. If you are using pre-Java8 version, then consider [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) for this task.

Below there's a sample code, that uses Apache Commons Codec for Base64 encoding (please note that import directive has been changed):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // composing string to be encoded
        sb.append("Part 1 of some text to be encoded to base64 format\n");
        sb.append("Part 2 of some text to be encoded to base64 format\n");
        sb.append("Part 3 of some text to be encoded to base64 format");


        // getting base64 encoded string bytes
        byte[] bytesEncoded =  Base64.encodeBase64(sb.toString().getBytes());

        // composing json
        String json = "{\"serialDataByte\":\""+ new String(bytesEncoded) +"\"}";        

        System.out.println(json);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Upon sending POST requests make sure that you have marked your request as a POST request. Do not forget this line of code, before making the request:

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

and use HttpURLConnection instead of URLConnection:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

Comment: the code uses Java 8 SDK. What java version do you use?

Comment: Still dint work, this is how my JSonobject {"serialData":"MTAzNDcxMDM0NzEwMzQ3MTAzNDcxMDM0NzEwMzQ3MTAzNDcxMDM0NzEwMzQ3","guProductID":"123456789","guStoreID":"123456","securityToken":"57b998ef02afa6957b94bd476c00e469"}

Comment: is it because am debuging locally both service and client?

Comment: it should not be the cause of the problem. Did you get "http invalid request error" (HTTP 400)?

Comment: @rafeal yes java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:3361/EcoService.svc/Json/saveSerialNumbers

Comment: plese make an update to your question and post the code of your client that makes HTTP POST request. I think there's a problem with your code. It is not related to JSON composing. Your JSON is ok, the problem is in your POST requesting code.

Comment: there is no `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");` invocation. Make sure you set `POST` type to your request. Because by default HTTP request is sending as a GET request. And seems that the size of your request exceeds the GET request limits and you get HTTP 400 error.

Comment: Use HttpUrlConnection instead of UrlConnection. Check the update of my answer

Comment: very strange. I would make a simple Apache Tomcat servlet and would send this POST request to this servlet. And in the servlet code I would print all request parameters. It will help to localise the problem. If you get all POST request parameters printed properly, then your client works ok and you need to check your server and it's settings.

Comment: is there anything to be done on the wcf service side?, also when i checked through the fiddler, there is no service call

Comment: I am not experienced with WCF in particular. Seems that there's something wrong on the server side, server settings. Make a simple servlet to check your POST request as I mentioned in previous comment, to be sure.